# Spark and YARN - how to work together with them

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I have a conceptual doubt.

It would be about YARN and SPARK, I have a 2 YARN (AM) 28GB with 4 CPUs and a WORKNODE of 56GB with 8 cpus.

I submit my applications always through the YARN yarn-cluster in the spark-submit option.

How do I use all memory and worknode cpus if the YARN server has fewer resources?

Can worknode settings overlap with YARN settings?

If my "spark.executor.memory" parameter is larger than the YARN memory, will it be used or not ?

With using the full potential of my worknode?

Comment: CPU usages in YARN cluster [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/32280/how-is-yarnnodemanagerresourcecpu-vcores-value-det.html)

Comment: [Tuning YARN](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html)

Comment: Ok thanks , but about spark ?

Comment: YARN will kill the container if the executor memory is higher than `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`